# How to give more space in gwt using &nbsp in ui.html file

Tags: java, gwt

First I tried with this, I got to see little space `<g:Label>&nbsp;</g:Label>`.
If I want more space then how can we utilize the above line of code or any other option.

Comment: Can you please post the sample code? what is the exact issue.

Comment: Do you mean `ui.xml` (not `ui.html`)? Do you want to have a piece of code - a _spacer_ that you could reuse in other places? Please, be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to use multiple spans with left-padding.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32515884)